# Javascript redirect when clicking on a div with a certain id

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, dom-events

Here is an example of what I need help with: http://www.arbutusroofing.com/roofing-services/

When the user clicks on “READ MORE” (under each subject or category) and the light grey box pops up with more information, I want it to automatically redirect to another page in 10 seconds.

I know how to redirect to a different page when an actual link is clicked, but not with certain events like this.

Here is some example of the code:

```
<h6 id="displayText" style="margin-top: 0px; cursor: pointer;"> 
<u>READ MORE</u> ABOUT FLAT ROOFING 
</h6>
```

I'm trying to redirect to a different page after 10 seconds when the id "displaytext" is clicked on.

Also, here is the code for the toggle text if you were wondering:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("div#toggleText").hide();
      $("h6#displayText").click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
        $(this).next("div#toggleText").slideToggle();
      });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: do you use jquery or an alternative? Or do you want a pure js solution. Can you show us some code?

Comment: You may want to have a look at Jquery for a start, and its [sliding effects](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/sliding/) for example

Comment: Here is the code:

<h6 id="displayText" style="margin-top: 0px; cursor: pointer;"> <u>READ MORE</u> ABOUT FLAT ROOFING </h6>

I'm looking to redirect to a different page when the id "displaytext" is clicked on.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You **JS** code:

```
   function OpenNewTab(id){
    setTimeout(function(){ window.location.href = "http://yourlinkhere/'+id+'"; }, 10000);

}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div onclick="OpenNewTab(1)">Readmore</div> // here 1 SHOULD BE UNIQUE ID AS PER RECORDS
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for the javascript function setTimeout.

```
setTimeout(function(){ window.location.href = "http://somehwereblahblah"; }, 10000);
```

Comment: absolutely not, although it's not clear until you follow the link in the question...

Comment: Thanks for you response.

Let me share the code with you:

<h6 id="displayText" style="margin-top: 0px; cursor: pointer;">
<u>READ MORE</u>
ABOUT FLAT ROOFING
</h6>

Although you're on the right track, I'm looking to redirect when the id "displaytext is clicked on; not when the window is on a certain link.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can execute code with a delay using the setTimout function.  An example of linking to google.com 10 seconds after the 'click' div is clicked:

```
<div onclick='setTimeout(function(){window.location = "http://www.google.com"}, 10000)'>Click</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use settimeout function. Eg:

```
setTimeout("location.href = 'http://insert-target-url';",1500);
```

setTimeout need two arguments. First is the action that will be executed. It can be simple redirect command, or event a function. The second one is the delay in milliseconds.

Hope this helps you.